# Compare approximate value to 6 decimal

Tags: python

I would like to ask how we can define a and b are actually same after approximation. I like to have True in the following case.

```
a = 59.9999999
b = 60.0000001
if (a==b):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: you need to define some threshold `if a-b < some_threshold: # they are equal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 59.9999999
b = 60.0000001
np.isclose([a],[b],atol =a-b)
#op
array([ True])
```